# Binding a GridView control to a DataTable

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, datatable

What is the sytnax for displaying a data table column on an ASP.NET page (.aspx)?  I know it it along the lines of `Container.DataItem`, it has been awhile since I worked with `DataTable` object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%#Databinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Field") %>
```